# TableSorter: scroll table with stickyHeaders to row with row id

Tags: jquery, scroll, tablesorter

I'm sorry for my english ..
could someone explain to me how to scroll a table with stickyHeaders and select a row using the row id?

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I posted your answer in the issue you opened on [GitHub](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/537).

For future reference, please post questions here at Stackoverflow, and report actual problems with the plugin (e.g. javascript errors or a feature that is not working as intended) at GitHub. Thanks!

I'll repost the answer here for prosperity:

---

Try this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2178/)):

HTML

```
<input id="gotorow" type="number" min="1" max="10" value="" />
```

Script

```
$('#gotorow').on('change', function () {
    window.location.hash = "#row" + this.value;
    var $row = $(window.location.hash),
        table = $row.closest('table')[0],
        // get sticky header height
        ht = table.config.widgetOptions.$sticky.height() || 27;
    $('body').scrollTop($row.position().top - ht);
});

$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders']
});
```